# AttributeError: What is wrong with this method?

Tags: python, tkinter

First problem is that I am getting an error:

"AttributeError: App instance has no attribute 'after'"

I think it has to do with the way I have declared countdown(), but I do not know excactly how to fix it.

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        master.title("Araña en la Cabaña")
        master.configure(background="black")

        master.puntuacion= Label(master, text="Araña en la Cabaña", font=("American Typewriter", 40),bg="black", fg="red", justify=CENTER)
        master.puntuacion.grid(row=0, column=2)

        master.team_A_label= Label(master, textvariable= team_A, font=("American Typewriter", 30),bg="black", fg="red")
        master.team_A_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
        master.team_B_label= Label(master, textvariable= team_B, font=("American Typewriter", 30),bg="black", fg="red")
        master.team_B_label.grid(row=1, column=3)

        master.team_A_score_label= Label(master, textvariable= team_A_score, font=("04B", 35),bg="black", fg="yellow").grid(row=2, column=1)

        master.team_B_score_label= Label(master, textvariable= team_B_score, font=("04B", 35),bg="black", fg="yellow")
        master.team_B_score_label.grid(row=2, column=3)

        master.team_at_play_label= Label(master, textvariable= team_at_play, font=("American Typewriter", 30),fg="yellow", bg="black")
        master.team_at_play_label.grid(row=3, column=2)

        master.pregunta_start = Label(master, text="¿Cómo se traduce....?", font=("American Typewriter", 30),fg="orange",bg="black")
        master.pregunta_start.grid(row=6, column=2)

        master.pregunta_finish = Label(master, textvariable = pregunta, font=("American Typewriter", 30),fg="green",bg="black")
        master.pregunta_finish.grid(row=7, column=2)

        master.clock_label = Label(master, text="El Reloj:", font=("American Typewriter", 20),fg="red",bg="black")
        master.clock_label.grid(row = 6, column= 0)

        master.reloj = Label(master, textvariable = time_left, font=("American Typewriter", 30),fg="red",bg="black")
        master.reloj.grid(row = 7, column= 0)
        master.team_answer = Entry(master, textvariable=team_answer, width=50)
        master.team_answer.grid(row=8, column=2)
        master.team_answer.focus_set()
        master.feedback_label = Label(textvariable= feedback, font=("American Typewriter", 30),fg="green",bg="black")
        master.feedback_label.grid(row=9, column=2)
        master.traduccion_label = Label(master, text = "La traducción correcta es:", font=("American Typewriter", 20),fg="green",bg="black")
        master.traduccion_label.grid(row=10, column=1)
        master.give_correct_answer = Label(master, textvariable = give_answer, font=("American Typewriter", 20), fg="green", bg="black")
        master.give_correct_answer.grid(row=10, column =2)
        master.respond_button = Button(master, text="Responder",bg="black", command=check_response, justify=CENTER, borderwidth=.001)
        master.respond_button.grid(row=10, column=3)
        master.bind("<Return>", check_response)

        master.continue_button = Button(master, text="Adelante", bg="black", command=player_turn)
        master.continue_button.grid(row=10, column=4)



    def countdown(master, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            remaining = remaining

        if remaining <= 0:
#             master.label.configure
            time_left.set("¡Se acabó el tiempo!")
        else:
#             master.reloj.configure(text="%d" % master.remaining)
            time_left.set(remaining)
            remaining = remaining - 1
            master.after(1000, master.countdown)
```

Answer (score 0):

`countdown` should take `self` as its first argument:

```
    def countdown(self, master, remaining = None):
        if remaining is not None:
            remaining = remaining

        if remaining <= 0:
#             master.label.configure
            time_left.set("¡Se acabó el tiempo!")
        else:
#             master.reloj.configure(text="%d" % master.remaining)
            time_left.set(remaining)
            remaining = remaining - 1
            master.after(1000, master.countdown)
```

As it is now, `master` points to the `App` instance, and what you expected to be passed as `master` was actually passed as `remaining`. Relatedly, I suspect your real code is something different if it gave you that particular error message, since with this code you should get errors a bit earlier.

Comment: Okay, so the order of arguments is important. Do I have it right when I think that in `def countdown(self, master, remaining= None):` the `self` will point to the `App` instance and now `master` points to the main frame widget that might have otherwise been referred to as the `root` widget? Should I have written `self.remaining = remaining`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is:

> "AttributeError: App instance has no attribute 'after'"

This means, somewhere you are doing `self.after(...)`, but you have not defined a method named `after`, and you haven't inherited one either. `after` is a method available to all tkinter widgets, but `App` isn't a widget and doesn't inherit from one.

Since you pass `master` in to the countdown method, and `master` is a widget, you can call after on it:

```
def countdown(self, master, ...):
    ...
    master.after(...)
```

Another solution is to save `master` as an attribute of the app, and use it instead of passing it to the function:

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    ...
def countdown(self, ...):
    ...
    self.master.after(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to better understand attributes and your explanation helps me toward this.

Comment: I was trying to be a good pythonic programer by adding self before each of the widgets in master, but it doesn't like me for it. Also, the countdown clock does not work. I've experimented with the arguments and tried to set remaining equal to something other than "none". Any suggestions?

Comment: @JimBaptista: well, you have other problems not related to the question you asked. For example, this statement isn't doing anything useful: `remaining = remaining`. Plus, you haven't handled the case where `remaining` _is_ `None`, which is what it will always be. My recommendation is to learn why and how you use `self` and what it represents, and what `master` represents. It seems like you're just cutting and pasting code hoping to find something that works.

Comment: That is right about the pasting. I guess with some of this stuff I feel a little bit over my head. As far as understanding `master` and `self` goes, I have yet to wrap my head around them. I'll keep trying.